# Jasper Mongodbquery - Aggregation query with multi selected parameter

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection with person data and i would like to make a report with a Multi select query. I want to see data of more people on same time. If i use Single Select  input control  with mongo query is working, but when i change the control to Multi Select then the report throw an error. How can i create a query with a collection parameter?

Parameter: PersonId ( org.bson.types.ObjectId )

Working query when i use Single Select :

```
{ runCommand: {
    aggregate : "personObject",
    pipeline : [
{$match : {_id :$P{PersonId}}},
{$project:{_id:1,personObjectName:1,receivedDate:1,}},
{$sort : {receivedDate : -1}}
                    ]
                            }
}
```

How can i change this query if i want to work with Multi Select?

Comment: Try `{$match : {_id : { '$in' : $P{CollectionParameter} } } }`

Comment: It's works. Thank you very much!